# Canopy Growth Corporation (CGC) Valuation

Tags: stocks, investing

I was looking at the financials of a Pot company and saw that over the past years, their *total assets* as well as their *equity* increased while at the same time, they were losing money and their *net income* was in the red.
Can someone explain how that is possible?

Thanks in advance for the answer!!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about that company specifically, but an equity investment would have that effect.

> When you, co-owners or investors make an equity investment in your
>   company, you increase the amount of additional paid-in capital under
>   owner's equity. Because your company's balance sheet must balance, the
>   cash used to pay for the equity investment gets recorded as cash under
>   short-term assets. If an investor contributed an asset, then the
>   asset's value gets recorded under long-term assets.
>
> Example
>
> You make a $50,000 equity investment in your company. You record this
>   as a $50,000 increase in additional paid-in capital under owner's
>   equity. You also record a $50,000 increase in cash under assets. An
>   investor also contributed a $30,000 equity investment in the form of a
>   used printing press. You record this investment in two locations on
>   the balance sheet. You increase additional paid-in capital by $30,000
>   and add printing press, $30,000 as a long-term asset. The net effect
>   of both investments on the balance sheet is an increase in both total
>   assets and owner's equity of $80,000.

[Citation](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/report-equity-investments-balance-sheet-65175.html)